# How to take multiple values from user as input using gridview in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to input values for a week in my website. To use multiple labels and textbox doesn't look nice.

Can I use gridview for that? and how? because gridview will always have modes as edit,cancel and not for input.

Are there any other control that will be more suitable to take this kind of multiple input from user?

Comment: You could use the FooterRow to insert records. http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article180.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I ask why you are not considering creating a user control that way you will be able to customise the the control just the way you want.

If thats not an option then yes you can use the gridview. This example will get you started

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/09/adding-dynamic-rows-in-asp.net-gridview-control-with-textboxes-and.aspx

http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-dynamic-input-rows-in-a-gridview-with-asp-net.aspx